# Yii2 GridView Custom Search TextBox

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

As the design require to use the search Textbox out site the gridview
what I want to do is to search from textbox outside the gridview by attribute 'name'.
I don't know the way or best practice how to do it. Please help!!!
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear .. what's the problem .. try expalin better ..  please

Comment: @scaisEdge what I want to do is to search from textbox outside the gridview by attribute 'name'. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is generated  by Gii you should have already available a `_search`  partial view for this .. otherwise  you can take a look at this guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html  .. at this section   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html

essentially as you can see in doc you should create a proper partial view

> ```
>     <div class="post-search">
>       <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
>           'action' => ['index'],
>           'method' => 'get',
>       ]); ?>
>
>       <?= $form->field($model, 'title') ?>
>
>       <?= $form->field($model, 'creation_date') ?>
>
>       <div class="form-group">
>           <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
>           <?= Html::submitButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
>       </div>
>
>       <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
>   </div>
> ```

and render it inside your grid view

with

> ```
>     <?= $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]) ?>
> ```

Comment: scaisEdge: What I have done is created by Gii and what I want to do it just want search from textbox outside the gridview(Not use default search). Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Essentially You have two way  1) you can customize the  _seach partial view provided by  gii  or 2) you can create a new action for a separated  gridvew  invokeation that build the dataProvider  using a new searchFunction  add in your serch model and create a ( copied and modified)

Comment: scaiseEdge Thanks so much